# How do i split a list into smaller lists based on keywords? (C# XNA)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

Hi I'm currently working on a importer for a C# / XNA application and I need some help with filtering out the input( a List of string where each line is a "new" string) into smaller chunks(smaller List of string).

This is a sample of how the input is divided into "frames" with the mesh and camera data necessary to create a "keyframe".

```
num_frames 4
start 1
end 24
frame_rate 24

frame 1
meshes 2
    name pCube1
        color F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/image2.gif
        bump F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/images.jpg
        bumpDepth 1
        vertices 36
            meshData...
    name pCube2
        color NONE
        bump none
        bumpDepth 0
        vertices 36
            meshData...
cameras 1
    name persp
        cameraData... 
frame 5
meshes 2
    name pCube1
        color F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/image2.gif
        bump F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/images.jpg
        bumpDepth 1
        vertices 36
            meshData...
    name pCube2
        color NONE
        bump none
        bumpDepth 0
        vertices 36
            meshData...
cameras 1
    name persp
cameraData...       
frame 10
meshes 2
    name pCube1
        color F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/image2.gif
        bump F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/images.jpg
        bumpDepth 1
        vertices 36
            meshData...
    name pCube2
        color NONE
        bump none
        bumpDepth 0
        vertices 36
            meshData...
cameras 1
    name persp
        cameraData...
frame 24
meshes 2
    name pCube1
        color F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/image2.gif
        bump F:/MayaImporterExporter/ImporterExporter/Bin/Textures/images.jpg
        bumpDepth 1
        vertices 36
            meshData...
    name pCube2
        color NONE
        bump none
        bumpDepth 0
        vertices 36
            meshData...
cameras 1
    name persp
        cameraData...
```

so the things i need to do is:

1. Split the input down into a smaller list containing the mesh and camera data for each keyframe .
2. Split the keyframe data into two lists( one for the meshes, and one to the cameras).
3. split the meshes/cameras into a List of List of Strings.
4. create the meshes and cameras form the "List of List of Strings"(I know this part ).

So I need some help to figure out how to filter out the input data into smaller chunks to create the meshes and cameras from the input.

Comment: Is it necessary to use this format? I imagine that it would be much simpler if this was XML. Then you could use XmlSerializer and LINQ to group your lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something similar to this:

```
       var lines = File.ReadAllLines( path )
                    .Select( s => s.Trim( ) )
                    .Where( s => s.Length > 0 ).ToArray( );
        int index = 0;

        void Next() { index++; }

        bool Peek(string token ) { return lines[index].StartsWith( token ) ;}

        string ReadStringValue  ( ) { 
           var value = lines[index].Split( ' ' )[1]; 
           Next( ); 
           return value; 
        };

        string ReadIntValue () { 
          var value = lines[index].Split( ' ' )[1]; 
          Next( ); 
          return int.Parse(value); 
        };

        Header ReadAnimation() {
           var anim= new Animation();
           while (index<lines.Length)
           {
               if (Peek("num_frames")) anim.NuMFrames = ReadIntValue();
               if (Peek("start")) ....
               if (Peek("frame")) anim.AddFrame( ReadFrame() );
           }

        }

        Frame ReadFrame() {
           if (Peek("frame")) {
              var frame = new Frame();
              frame.Index = ReadIntValue();
              ReadMeshes( frame );
              ReadCameras( frame );                  
              return frame;
           }
           return null;
        }

        void ReadMeshes(Frame frame)
        {
            if (Peek("meshes")) {
                int count = ReadIntValue();
                for (int i =0; i<count; i++) {
                    frame.Meshes.Add( ReadMesh() );
                }
            }
        }

        Mesh ReadMesh() {
           ....
        }
```

Comment: that's somewhat how I would solve that part, but i can't really figure out how to filter out the lines to the corresponding "frame".

Comment: You should implment the methods ReadFrame, ReadMeshes, ReadMesh, ReadCameras, ReadCamera, and determine when reading a block is finnished, usually when you Peek an item that you dont expect

Comment: I've adde some code.. realize that it can be improved... its only a guide... you couald add a Parse method to your objects, with a ParserContext agument where common data is stored...

Comment: what i meant was more like, how do i stop the 1st frame from ranging from the 1st occurrence of the keyword "frame" to the end of the file, and the 2de frame from ranging from the 2de occurrence of the keyword "frame" to the end of the file, and so on.

Comment: you dont need to do nothing... when the parser ends reading a Camera block inside a Frame block, it returns to the upper level.. and if the parser find a line starting with "frame" it will read that new frame .. if there is no more lines to read it will end

Comment: I've now successfully implement the importer, I wasn't able to fully implement your solution, but I managed to create one using yours as a source of inspiration/ starting point.

Answer (score 0):

After some failed attempts on successfully implement the importer, I finally figured out how to make it work.

```
namespace Importer
{
class ImportHandler
{

    List<string> inputString;
    Readanyfile read= new Readanyfile();
    int num_frames, start, end, frame_rate;
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;
    classes_stat.KeyFrameAnimation Animation;
    public ImportHandler(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Game game,string _inputFile)
    {
        this.graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
        this.inputString = read.Load();
        ReadRawScene();
    }


    string ReadStringValue(string str)
    {
        var value = str.Split(' ')[1]; 

       return value; 
    }
    public int strToInt(string str)
    {
        var value = str.Split(' ')[1]; 
       return int.Parse(value); 

    }
    public float strToFloat(string str)
    {
        var value = str.Split(' ')[1]; 
        return float.Parse(value);

    }
    public double strToDouble(string str)
    {
        var value = str.Split(' ')[1]; 
        try
        {
            return double.Parse(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch
        {
            return (double) 0.1f;
        }



    }
     private static float[] ParseFloatArray(string str, int count)
    {
        var floats = new float[count];

        var segments = str.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (i < segments.Length)
            {
                try
                {
                    floats[i] = (float)double.Parse(segments[i], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                catch
                {
                    floats[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return floats;
    }
private Vector2 ParseVector2(string str)
    {
        var components = ParseFloatArray(str, 3);

        var vec = new Vector2(components[0], components[1]);

        return components[2] == 0
            ? vec
            : vec / components[2];
    }


    private Vector3 ParseVector3(string str)
    {
        var components = ParseFloatArray(str, 4);

        var vec = new Vector3(components[0], components[1], components[2]);

        return components[3] == 0
            ? vec
            : vec / components[3];
    }
    public void ReadRawScene()
    {
        List<classes_stat.KeyFrame> tempAni = new List<classes_stat.KeyFrame>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Count(); i++ )
        {
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("num_frames"))
            {
                num_frames = strToInt(inputString[i]);
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("start"))
            {
                start = strToInt(inputString[i]);
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("end"))
            {
                end = strToInt(inputString[i]);
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("frame_rate"))
            {
                frame_rate = strToInt(inputString[i]);
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("frame"))
            { tempAni.Add(ReadFrames(strToInt(inputString[i]), i, inputString));
            }
            Animation = new classes_stat.KeyFrameAnimation(frame_rate, start, end, num_frames, tempAni);

        }

    }
    public classes_stat.KeyFrame ReadFrames(int frameIndex,int currentIndex, List<string> inputString )
    {
        List<MeshFromBinary> tempOutPutMesh = new List<MeshFromBinary>();
        List<CameraFromBinary> tempOutPutCam = new List<CameraFromBinary>();
        for (int i = currentIndex + 3; i < inputString.Count(); i++)
        {

            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("meshes"))
            {



                int count = strToInt(inputString[i]);

                for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
                {

                    MeshFromBinary temp = ReadMeshes(i, inputString);
                    tempOutPutMesh.Add(temp);

                }

            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("cameras"))
            {
                int count = strToInt(inputString[i]);

                for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
                {
                    tempOutPutCam.Add(ReadCameras(i, inputString));
                }
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("frame"))
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        classes_stat.KeyFrame frame = new classes_stat.KeyFrame(frameIndex, tempOutPutMesh, tempOutPutCam);
        return frame;
    }
    private MeshFromBinary ReadMeshes(int currentIndex, List<string> inputString)
    {

        int tempCurrentIndex = 0;
        List<classes_stat.MyOwnVertexFormat> temp = new List<classes_stat.MyOwnVertexFormat>();
        string name;
        Texture2D color = ContentTextures.crateTexture; 
        Texture2D bump = ContentTextures.crateTexture;
        double bumpDepth = 0;
        List<Vector3> tmpPos = new List<Vector3>();
        List<Vector3> tmpNor = new List<Vector3>();
        List<Vector3> tmpTan = new List<Vector3>();
        List<Vector2> tmpUV = new List<Vector2>();
        int numberofvertices = 0;
        for (int i = currentIndex; i < inputString.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("name"))
            {


                name = ReadStringValue(inputString[i]);
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("color"))
            {
                string tmp = ReadStringValue(inputString[i]);
                System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(tmp, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                color = Texture2D.FromStream(graphicsDevice, stream);
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
                //temp.Add(ReadStringValue());
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("normalMap"))
            {
                string tmp = ReadStringValue(inputString[i]);
                System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(tmp, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                bump = Texture2D.FromStream(graphicsDevice, stream);
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("bumpDepth"))
            {
                bumpDepth = strToDouble(inputString[i]);
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("vertices"))
            {
                numberofvertices = strToInt(inputString[i]);

            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("v"))
            {
                tempCurrentIndex = (i - 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = tempCurrentIndex; i < inputString.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("v"))
            {

                tmpPos.Add(ParseVector3(inputString[i]));

            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("vn"))
            {

                tmpNor.Add(ParseVector3(inputString[i]));
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("t"))
            {

                tmpTan.Add(ParseVector3(inputString[i]));

            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("vt"))
            {
                tmpUV.Add(ParseVector2(inputString[i]));
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("cameras"))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("name"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofvertices; i++)
        {

            temp.Add(new classes_stat.MyOwnVertexFormat(tmpPos[i], tmpNor[i], tmpTan[i], tmpUV[i]));

        }
        MeshFromBinary mMesh;
        return mMesh = new MeshFromBinary(graphicsDevice, temp, color, bump, bumpDepth);
    }
    private CameraFromBinary ReadCameras(int currentIndex, List<string> inputString)
    {
        int tempCurrentIndex = 0;
        CameraFromBinary temp;
        string name;
        Vector3 tmpPos = new Vector3();
        Vector3 tmpDir = new Vector3();
        Vector3 tmpUp = new Vector3();
        double tmpV_FOV = new double();
        double tmpH_FOV = new double(); 
        double tmpNear_clipping_plane = new double();
        double tmpFar_clipping_plane = new double();
        double tmpAspect_ratio = new double();
        for (int i = currentIndex; i < inputString.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("name"))
            {

                System.Console.WriteLine(ReadStringValue(inputString[i]));
                name = ReadStringValue(inputString[i]);

                tempCurrentIndex = (i + 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = tempCurrentIndex; i < inputString.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (inputString[i].StartsWith("eye"))
            {
                tmpPos = ParseVector3(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("up"))
            {
                tmpUp = ParseVector3(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("rotXYZ"))
            {
                tmpDir = ParseVector3(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("v_fov"))
            {
                tmpV_FOV = strToDouble(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("h_fov"))
            {
                tmpH_FOV = strToDouble(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("near_clipping_plane"))
            {
                tmpNear_clipping_plane = strToDouble(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("far_clipping_plane"))
            {
                tmpFar_clipping_plane = strToDouble(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("aspect_ratio"))
            {
                tmpAspect_ratio = strToDouble(inputString[i]);
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("frame"))
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("cameras"))
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (inputString[i].StartsWith("name"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return temp = new CameraFromBinary(tmpPos, tmpDir, tmpV_FOV, tmpAspect_ratio, tmpNear_clipping_plane, tmpFar_clipping_plane);
    }
}
}
```